# How to implement Google OAuth in an Ionic 2 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-oauth, ionic2, ionic-view

I need to add Google login in my Ionic v2 app.

Currently I cannot use the [Ionic Authentication service](http://ionic.io/platform#authentication) because it's [not ready for v2 yet](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-platform-beta-support/46110/2).

I've also tried the [ng2-cordova-oauth](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/use-ng2-cordova-oauth-for-all-your-ionic-2-oauth-needs) plugin but I cannot use `ionic serve` or [Ionic View](http://view.ionic.io/) to test the authentication which is a huge inconvenience for me because I no longer have an easy way to show the app to the client.

So... any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase user authentication is an alternative , you can implement google authentification with few lines of code

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

please see the documentation here [firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html)

Comment: I'm currently using this solution but there's a limitation. Firebase doesn't refresh Google's OAuth access token so it will expire after 1 hour. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZPW3xtwn8g0

Comment: Firebase google oauth is not working now according to this thread: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/243